# error C2955 template+operator

Tags: c++

I need some Help with this small code that includes re-def of operator and Template
But I keep getting this error:

> error C2955 use of class template requires template argument list

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class student
{
    friend int operator+(student &other1,student &other2);
public:
    student(T g);
private:
    int grade;
};
template <class T>
student<T>::student(T g)
{
    grade=g;

}

void main()
{

    student<int> s1(40),s2(90);
    int sum;
    sum=s1+s2;
    cout<<"average="<<sum/2.0<<endl;

}//main
template <class T>
int operator+(student &other1,student &other2)
{

    return other1.grade+other2.grade;
}
```

Comment: Try `int operator+(student<T> &other1,student<T> &other2)`

Comment: and in addition make the friend declaration a template as well. also, `void main` should be `int main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say

```
template<class T>
int operator+(student<T> a, student<T> b)
...
```

You were missing the T